# Trying to understand the differences across these promises and setTimeouts

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, settimeout

I'm learning about promises, setTimeout and async calls and have done a great job of confusing myself. I think I'm lacking some understanding around the callback and how setTimeout works. I've been looking at Mozilla documentation and the various Stackoverflow posts regarding these topics. I'm still having some trouble wrapping my head around why some of the functions I've created behave the way they do regarding the timeouts that are set.

Between `wait0` and `wait1` I don't understand why the timeout for `wait0` works properly and `wait1` doesn't adhere to it. With `wait2` it is like `wait1` except wrapped in an arrow function expression. Why does that make the timeout work properly? `wait3` isn't actually using the callback so that makes sense why the `promise` and `then` functions don't do anything. But it stops `wait4` from running. Is it blocking progression indefinitely or actually ending execution? For `wait4` I'm also not passing a value into the callback like with `wait0` but the timeout isn't being adhered to.

```
function wait0() {
    return new Promise((resolve, failure)=>{
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
  });
}

function wait1() {
    return new Promise((resolve, failure)=>{
    setTimeout(resolve('resolved ' + new Date().toGMTString()), 2000);
  });
}

function wait2() {
    return new Promise((resolve, failure)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
        resolve('resolved ' + new Date().toGMTString());
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function wait3() {
    return new Promise((resolve, failure)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{}, 2000);
  });
}

function wait4() {
    return new Promise((resolve, failure)=>{
    setTimeout(resolve(), 2000);
  });
}

async function test() {
  await wait0().then((result)=>console.log(result)); // Works as expected
  console.log(new Date().toGMTString());
    await wait1().then((result)=>console.log(result)); // Doesn't adhere to timeout
  console.log(new Date().toGMTString());
  await wait2().then((result)=>console.log(result)); // Works as expected
  console.log(new Date().toGMTString());
  await wait3().then((result)=>console.log(result)); // Never resolves
  console.log(new Date().toGMTString());
  await wait4().then((result)=>console.log(result)); // Doesn't adhere to timeout
  console.log(new Date().toGMTString());
}


test();
```

Comment: In wait1, you call resolve and assign what it returns to the timeout. You do the same thing in wait4

Comment: `setTimeout` takes a function to execute at a later time. In `wait1`, you execute `resolve()` immediately, resolving the promise. Whatever is returned from `resolve()` (probably nothing) is then passed to `setTimeout` to be executed in the future. Researching "first class functions" may help here. You can also use an inline anonymous "fat arrow" function `setTimeout(() => resolve(...), 2000)` which creates a function that setTimeout will later call.